# Struct pointer doesn't save character array as expected

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct _Text { 
  char *str; 
  int length; 
  int counter; 
  } *Text;


int main(void) {
  Text txt= malloc(sizeof(Text));
  char *txtStr="hi";
  txt->str=txtStr;
  return 0;
}
```

The struct simply doesn't work as expected, the char array given is not saved properly when checked.

Comment: At least `Text txt= malloc(sizeof(*Text));`, because `sizeof(Text)` is only the size of the pointer...

Comment: Because `Text` is a pointer type, then `sizeof(Text)` will result in the size of a pointer, which will be different from the size of the actual structure you need to allocate space for. Replace `malloc(sizeof(Text))` with `malloc(sizeof *txt)`.

Comment: And please don't create type-aliases of pointers (like `Text`). That makes the code harder to read and understand (and therefore maintain). It's also makes it easier to make mistakes like the one you made.

Comment: belive me, if i could i wouldn't use it, but im forced to, some teachers are kind of special i guess

Comment: As another note, the structure tag names (for example your `_Text`) lives in their own *namespace*, which means you can have a structure tag and a type-alias of the same name. So `typedef struct Text { ... } Text;` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Lundin yeah, like the (in)famous `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef struct Text { 
  char *str; 
  int length; 
  int counter; 
  } Text;
```

is better to read

and then

```
int main(void) {
  Text *txt = malloc( sizeof( Text ));
  
  txt->str = malloc( sizeof( char ) *3);
  strcpy( txt->str, "hi" );

  printf("%s\n", txt->str );
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in the UPV? I recognize this typedef because I am also struggling with tomorrow's assignment. I asked Oscar and he told me that you need to memory allocate space for the structure within the constructor of the class. He even provide me with some example code, yet I haven't managed to make it work yet.